# Variables not working outside of anonymous function in external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nice touchscreen button that responds to the user's touch (looks like iOS button), the JavaScript works fine inside the html document, but will not work at all in an external file:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Custom buttons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ontouchstart=''>

<div class="round-button iOS-border">
    <div class="round"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.round-button{
max-width: 50px;
max-height: 30px;
background-color: #fefefe;
padding: 0px 3px 1px 0px;
border-radius: 1000px;


transition:.3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
}

.round-button .round {
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 100%;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #c1c1c1;
border:  .5px solid #d7d7d7;

transition:.3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
}


.round-button:hover .round {
left: 22px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
iButtonOn = '#4cda62';
iButtonOff = '#fefefe';
iButtonBorder = '1px solid #e1e1e1';


document.querySelector('.round-button').ontouchstart = function() {
var round = document.querySelector('.round-button');
    document.querySelector('.round').style.left = '21px';
    round.style.background = iButtonOn;
    round.style.border = '1px solid transparent';
}

document.querySelector('.round-button').ontouchmove = function() {
var round = document.querySelector('.round-button');
    document.querySelector('.round').style.left = '0px';
    round.style.background = iButtonOff;
    round.style.border = iButtonBorder;
}


// Default styles
document.body.onload = function() {
var round = document.querySelector('.round-button');
    round.style.border = iButtonBorder; // loads default style

}
```

I tried putting `var` before `iButtonOn, iButtonOff,iButtonBorder`, and then putting it in a seperate function that starts on body load (like `<body onload="function()">`) but that still doesn't work.

The output looks like this, when the javascript is inside the document:

[image: Inside document]

Outside Document:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is being executed before the page loads. Move it to the end or wrap it in a `window.onload` handler function.